# how to pass a parameter in the Header with multipartFormData

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, microservices

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/uploadCV" , consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<?> uploadCV(@RequestHeader("token") String token,
                                      @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile cvFile) throws Exception {
        log.info(token + cvFile.getOriginalFilename()));
        return curriculumService.addCurriculum(token, pdfFile);
    }
```

If i use MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE don't get the value "token" :
2022-11-11 16:13:28.040  WARN 7283 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingRequestHeaderException: Required request header 'token' for method parameter type String is not present]

If i use MediaType.MULTIPART_MIXED_VALUE don't get file:
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found

how can i do?

Answer (score 1):

The code that you have written with `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE` is absolutely correct. It is very clear from error message what is the issue.

```
2022-11-11 16:13:28.040 WARN 7283 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingRequestHeaderException: Required request header 'token' for method parameter type String is not present]
```

**Issue:**

Code is expecting header name with key **token** should present in the request but it is not present.

**Solution:**

Please add header name with key **token** like this and try again.

[image]

Comment: i'm trying to test it with swagger and there doesn't show up, now i try with postman, thanks

Comment: Did you try with Postman?

Comment: Yes, i tried, the problem was swagger not allowing me to pass token through the interface. with Postaman it work, thanks!